# Unity blur renderer doesn't work on skybox/transparent images?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

Im using a gaussian blur asset that uses this script attached to the camera to make its shader blur what is behind the UI:

```
    public class BlurRenderer : MonoBehaviour
    {


        [Range(0, 25)]
        /// <summary>
        /// how many Iterations should the blur be applied for
        /// </summary>
        public int Iterations;

        [Range(0, 5)]
        /// <summary>
        /// Lowers the resolution of the texture, thus allowing for a larger blur without so many iterations
        /// </summary>
        public int DownRes;

        /// <summary>
        /// Weather to update the blur
        /// </summary>
        public bool UpdateBlur = true;

        /// <summary>
        /// amount of time that will pass before re-rendering the blur
        /// </summary>
        public float UpdateRate = 0.02f;

        /// <summary>
        /// last time we rendered the blur
        /// </summary>
        private float lastUpdate = 0.0f;

        /// <summary>
        /// Stores the blur texture between renders
        /// </summary>
        public RenderTexture BlurTexture;

        /// <summary>
        /// The material where we'll pass the screen texture though to create the blur
        /// </summary>
        private Material mat;



        private void Start()
        {
            //set up the blur texture

            BlurTexture = new RenderTexture(256, 256, 16, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);

            /*
            //we can swap the code above for a texture that will take up less ram...if needed.
            BlurTexture = new RenderTexture(128, 128, 4, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB4444);
            */

            //create the texture
            BlurTexture.Create();

            //create our material if we have not already
            if (mat == null)
            {
                mat = new Material(Shader.Find("Hidden/GaussianBlur_Mobile"));
            }
        }


        #region BlurScaleSlider

        //this section will enable a slider that controls both the Iterations and DownRes
        //Uncomment the code below to use it

        /*
        [Range(0, 100)]
        /// <summary>
        /// The blur scale.
        /// </summary>
        public int blurScale;

        private void Update()
        {
            int tempBlurScale = blurScale;

            Iterations = 0;
            DownRes = 0;

            while (tempBlurScale > 20 && DownRes < 5)
            {
                DownRes += 1;
                tempBlurScale -= 15;
            }

            Iterations = tempBlurScale;

            tempBlurScale = 0;
        }
        */

        #endregion

        //OnRenderImage will execute before each frame renders
        void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture src, RenderTexture dst)
        {
            // if we need to re-render
            if (Time.time - lastUpdate >= UpdateRate
                && UpdateBlur)
            {
                //set the width and height
                int width = src.width >> DownRes;
                int height = src.height >> DownRes;

                //create a temp texture
                RenderTexture rt = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(width, height);

                //move the screen image to our temp texture
                Graphics.Blit(src, rt);

                //loop to add the blur to our temp texture
                for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
                {
                    RenderTexture rt2 = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(width, height);
                    Graphics.Blit(rt, rt2, mat);
                    RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(rt);
                    rt = rt2;
                }

                //store our texture in BlurTexture
                Graphics.Blit(rt, BlurTexture);

                //set the global texture for our shader to use
                Shader.SetGlobalTexture("_MobileBlur", rt);

                //remove the temp texture
                RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(rt);

                //set lastUpdate
                lastUpdate = Time.time;

            }
            else
            {
                //set the global texture again...must be done for each frame
                Shader.SetGlobalTexture("_MobileBlur", BlurTexture);
            }

            //make sure the camera renders as normal.
            Graphics.Blit(src, dst);

        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a BlurRenderer_Mobile on the main camera
        /// </summary>
        static public BlurRenderer Create()
        {
            BlurRenderer BRM = Camera.main.gameObject.GetComponent<BlurRenderer>();

            if (BRM == null)
            {
                BRM = Camera.main.gameObject.AddComponent<BlurRenderer>();
            }

            return BRM;
        }

        //override to allow different camera
        static public BlurRenderer Create(Camera ThisCamera)
        {

            BlurRenderer BRM = ThisCamera.gameObject.GetComponent<BlurRenderer>();

            if (BRM == null)
            {
                BRM = ThisCamera.gameObject.AddComponent<BlurRenderer>();
            }

            return BRM;
        }

    }
}
```

It creates a render texture of what the camera renders in world space. This works with most game objects, but with my skybox background or fade Standard shader (with a transparent image in the slot), nothing renders.

With game object:
[image]

With just transparent image:
[image]

How can I fix this/what is causing this?

The shader:

```
Properties
    {
        [PerRendererData] _MainTex ("_MainTex", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Lightness ("_Lightness", Range(0,2)) = 1

        _Saturation ("_Saturation", Range(-10,10)) = 1

        _TintColor ("_TintColor",Color) = (1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0)


         // required for UI.Mask
         [HideInInspector] _StencilComp ("Stencil Comparison", Float) = 8
         [HideInInspector] _Stencil ("Stencil ID", Float) = 0
         [HideInInspector] _StencilOp ("Stencil Operation", Float) = 0
         [HideInInspector] _StencilWriteMask ("Stencil Write Mask", Float) = 255
         [HideInInspector] _StencilReadMask ("Stencil Read Mask", Float) = 255
         [HideInInspector] _ColorMask ("Color Mask", Float) = 15
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags
        {
            "Queue" = "Transparent"
            "PreviewType" = "Plane"
            "DisableBatching" = "True"
        }

        // required for UI.Mask
        Stencil
        {
            Ref [_Stencil]
            Comp [_StencilComp]
            Pass [_StencilOp] 
            ReadMask [_StencilReadMask]
            WriteMask [_StencilWriteMask]
        }
        ColorMask [_ColorMask]

        Pass
        {
            ZWrite Off
            Cull Off
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                half4 color : COLOR;
                half4 screenpos : TEXCOORD2;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float2 screenuv : TEXCOORD1;
                half4 color : COLOR;
                float2 screenpos : TEXCOORD2;
            };

            v2f vert(appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                o.screenuv = ((o.vertex.xy / o.vertex.w) + 1) * 0.5;
                o.color = v.color;
                o.screenpos = ComputeScreenPos(o.vertex);
                return o;
            }

            float2 safemul(float4x4 M, float4 v)
            {
                float2 r;

                r.x = dot(M._m00_m01_m02, v);
                r.y = dot(M._m10_m11_m12, v);

                return r;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_TexelSize;
            // x contains 1.0/width
            // y contains 1.0/height
            // z contains width
            // w contains height

            uniform float _Lightness;
            uniform float _Saturation;
            uniform fixed4 _TintColor;

            uniform sampler2D _MobileBlur;

            float4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                float4 m = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);

                float2 uvWH = float2(_MainTex_TexelSize.z / _ScreenParams.x,_MainTex_TexelSize.w / _ScreenParams.y);
                uvWH.x *= _MainTex_TexelSize.x;
                uvWH.y *= _MainTex_TexelSize.y;

                float2 buv = float2(i.screenpos.x - (uvWH.x / 2),i.screenpos.y - (uvWH.y / 2));

                float4 blurColor = float4(0,0,0,0);
                blurColor = tex2D(_MobileBlur,buv);
                //blurColor = tex2D(_MobileBlur,buv);

                blurColor.a *= m.a;

                float4 finalColor = blurColor * i.color;
                finalColor.a = i.color.a * m.a * blurColor.a;


                finalColor.rgb *= _Lightness;
                finalColor.rgb *= _TintColor;


                float3 intensity = dot(finalColor.rgb, float3(0.299,0.587,0.114));
                finalColor.rgb = lerp(intensity, finalColor.rgb  , _Saturation);

                return finalColor;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
```

Comment: I'ld say this depends more on how the `Hidden/GaussianBlur_Mobile` shader works than on the code you provided.

Comment: @derHugo check my edit

Comment: Works well for me, maybe you exclude them from the camera mask?

Comment: To me it seems that the shader is only applied where the background of that panel is not transparent. Maybe you need to overlapping panels, one only for the blur, the other to add the black faded color?

Comment: possibly in the lines `blurColor.a *= m.a;` and/or `finalColor.a = i.color.a * m.a * blurColor.a;` where you use the alpha value of the original material. I'm not sure but you could try to change it maybe to `blurColor.a = 1`; (or `255` I'm no shader expert and don't know the correct color format here) Though I guess then it might be blurred on the entire image rect and not only in the form of your texture ... might overcome this combining it with a `Mask` evtl

Comment: Thank you so incredibly much that was it.